# VB.Net Regular Expression that allows spaces

Tags: regex, vb.net

How to I create a RegEx that allows string input (letters) and allows spaces?

Originally I used:`"^[a-zA-Z]+$"`

But then I tried: `"^[a-zA-Z_]+$"`

Can't seem to get anything that works. Just need a RegEx that allows lower and upper character letters for location names with spaces, like "Alton Leisure Centre" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex won't allow spaces at the start or at the last.

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yP1kI0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

This should do it for you.